# Setting a class variable from a global function

Tags: php, methods

Trying to do something like this:

```
Class Example {
    public static $current_item;
}

function example_global($var1) {
    if ($var1)
        Example::$current_item = $var1;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Public property is available for read/write from any context. That is the meaning of `public`. So static property has no difference.

Comment: Yes that's right, what problem are you witnessing ?

Comment: It should be working, but it does not seem to be.  The variable is not being set.  Does it matter if the function I am attempting to set the class variable from was included(require_once) using said class?

Comment: Your code is fine. Yes make sure to include that class first where you are using it.

Comment: @GregL yes, you need to include the Class

Comment: I did include the class, thank you guys. The issue was I was trying to error_log(print_r(Example::$current_item)) inside the class.  It was failing - so I believed it was not being set.  While I have your attention - why does error_log not work within a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work with a little problem: be carefull with this:

```
if ($var1)
```

because you will not be able to set the value 0

Answer (score 1):

The code works:

```
Class Example {
    public static $current_item;
}

function example_global($var1) {
    if ($var1)
        Example::$current_item = $var1;

}

example_global('hello there!<br>');
echo Example::$current_item;
example_global('hello there again!');
echo Example::$current_item;
```

Result:

```
hello there!
hello there again!
```

So make sure to include the class in file where you are using it first.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` variable `$current_item` in the Example class will be set with the arbitrary value that was passed from the function.

Say if you pass `example_global($50);` , the `$current_item` value is going to be set.

```
<?php

Class Example {
    public static $current_item;
}

function example_global($var1) {
    if ($var1)
        Example::$current_item = $var1;
}

example_global(20);
var_dump(Example::$current_item);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
(int) 20
```

Even, if you remove the `public` modifier , that is going to work .

From the PHP Docs..

> if no visibility declaration is used, then the property or method will
>   be treated as if it was declared as public.

Comment: What's the point of converting comment (applicable) to answer?

Comment: OP is not asking about how to call the function.

Comment: I am not asking how to call the function.  I am asking how to set the class variable using example_global()

Comment: @GregL, When you call the function.. the variable is going to be set.

Comment: Just do a `var_dump(Example::$current_item);` after you call that function.. you will see the variable is set.